# True if not null in SQL for Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

Is there a better way to get false when not null, and true when null? I cannot find a better way in the documentation.

```
SELECT
  item_id                           as item_id
  case some_field
    when NULL
    then FALSE else TRUE
  end                               as is_active
FROM some_table
```

Comment: "True if not null" or "false when not null"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `is null` construct instead.

For example:

```
select *, f is null as y from t
```

Result:

```
 f     y     
 ----- ----- 
 0     false 
 1     false 
 null  true
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6YgY9HLtbHM7g7uBXqeNk/0).